# Menu is never collapsing

Tags: html, css

When this website is gonna to smaller viewports, there is showing a burger menu. The following menu options is having submenus:

- Companyname
- Webshop

When you see the burger menu, it is not visible to see that those menu items is having submenu items. If you click on "Rådgivning", there is coming a small red arrow to the right.

I would like that red arrow to be there all the time, so it is visible there is sub menu items

But I cannot figure out how I am making the small arrow show all the time. I cannot find the class in the css.

Can somebody give me a hint?

```
<li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-52">
   <a href="#">Rådgivning</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu hide">
       <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="#">Aftercheck</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find what was the problem.
Add this code before the `</head>` tag.

```
<style>
.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    border-top: 7px solid #cc0000;
}
</style>
```

OR
If you can edit this file: *removed link* style.css 
Search this code `.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a:hover:after` and just delete `:hover`

Comment: You can also change the color if you want using the first solution. Then on hover it will turn red, to mark as active.

Comment: Great thank you rxdue. Can you do me a big favor, and remove the link to the site, so the  company name is not indexed with the link you posted. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code (CSS).

Looking at your site through Chrome Dev Tools, you've set your dropdown icons to appear on hover. For a mobile site, hover does not exist, the browser will treat a tap with properties of :hover & :visited.

Here is a look at your code:

```
.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a:hover:after {
    border-top: 7px solid #cc0000;
}
```

By removing ":hover" your dropdown icons will appear naturally.
Go try it! Visit your site and inspect the element, remove the ":hover" selector and voila they appear.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 0):

Although, I havent seen your stylesheet, but from what I can see in the link, you are using CSS pseudo class, which only toggle the arrow either on hover or on active.

What you need is a JavaScript function to be triggered each time there is a click on the menu item.

This is what I did:

1. give all arrow parent container a unique id
2. Add click event to call a function
3. With function toggle classes of the arrow.

See sample below

Css

```
#menu-item-52{
width:300px;
height: auto;
background:white;
border: 0.5px solid grey;
list-style-type: none;
overflow:hidden;
user-select: none;
}

.menu-text{
display:block;
float:left;
}

.arrow{
float: right;
width:20px;
height: 1px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-left: 16px solid;
border-top:10px solid 
transparent;
border-right: none;
border-bottom:10px solid 
transparent;
transition: transform 1s;
}
.rotate{
transform: rotate(90deg);
right: 20px;
top: 20px;
position: absolute;
}
#link{
display: block;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
height: 20px;  
}
.menu-item-51{
display: block;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.sub-menu{
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: height     
0.5s;
}
.hide{
height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class = 'main-menu-items' 
id="menu-item-52" onclick = 
'openSubCon(this.id)'>
 <a id = 'link'>
  <div class = 'menu-text'>
    Rådgivning
  </div>
  <div class = 'arrow'></div>
 </a>

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li class="menu-item- 
   51">item-1</li>
  <li class="menu-item- 
   51">item-2</li>
 </ul>
```

Javascript

```
function openSubCon(elem){

document.getElementById(elem).
getEl ementsByClassName('sub- 
menu')[0].classList.toggle
('hide');

document.getElementsByClassName
('arrow'[0].classList.toggle 
('rotate');
}
```

In case you are using web icons, you can toggle display or each of the arrow down and arrow side. Hope that helps.